# Why does VSCode's type checking of function parameters ignore type object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I am using VSCode as my editor, have enabled its [type checking feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript), and added a [JSDoc block tag](https://jsdoc.app/about-block-inline-tags.html) defining type of parameters the function should take (see code below).  How can have VSCode's type checking feature report when this function is passed a parameter other than an object?  If I set the type as `object` in the block tag, then call the function while passing a number value, there is no violation flagged in VSCode (see screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urqgc.jpg)).  Why is that--shouldn't this be flagged as a type violation?

[The JSDoc page on `@param`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html) indicates, "The parameter type can be a built-in JavaScript type, such as string or Object."

If I define the input parameter to be of type `string` instead of `object`, then call the function while passing a parameter of type `number`, there *is* a violation flagged, as expected ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NorFO.jpg)).

Thanks.

---

**My Function + JSDoc Block Tag**

```
/**
 * Test description
 *
 * @param {string} myVar - Description of myVar.

 */
const myFunc = myVar => {
  return myVar
}
```

Comment: Your example works in the TypeScript playground. Make sure your `tsconfig.json` has `"allowJs: true"`.

Comment: @xAlien95 OK thanks for confirming functionality in the TS playground.  I can try editing my tsconfig.json.  But how exactly do I edit that file/where is that file located? 
Just to be clear, my project itself does not have a tsconfig.json file, nor is TypeScript explicitly installed.  The type checking that is occurring in this case, is type checking done by VSCode, which itself uses its own bundled version of TypeScript.  Maybe what you 've told me means this is probably a VSCode issue, rather than a TS issue.